# jersey client performance on entity reading

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I have a very smilar jersey client as below. If client and sever are at same machine

> response.getEntity(String.class)

line takes only nanoseconds but if client and server are at different machines this takes 250-300 miliseconds. I tried this on both jersey 1 and jersey 2 but the result didn't changed. Do you have any idea?

```
package com.mkyong.client;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClientGet {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/get");

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                   .get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatus());
        }

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        System.out.println(output);

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be related to the network latency? Can you check the delay in ping?

Comment: I replaced grizzly with jetty and now it works how i expected. I really didn't understand how this fixed my problem but the only thing i changed was the web server.